# date method not working properly in groovy

Tags: groovy

i have this

```
    class MainController {
    def test = {

    def day1 =1
    def month1 = 10
    def year1 = 2011

    def date1 = new Date(year1 ,month1, day1);
    }
   }
```

But the OutPut is

```
    Wed Nov 01 00:00:00 PKT 3911
```

Why its 3911 , shouldnt it be 2011 ??

Any solution

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the Date API of this deprecated constructor. You must pass in the year-1900. Also, the month is zero-based (also in the API docs).

That information was also shown in my answer to one of your previous questions.

Comment: Thanks , it worked !   Now the output is  Sat Oct 01 00:00:00 PKT 2011  which is correct , but can i remove this 01 00:00:00 PKT? thanks